# Using fn:sum in XSLT with node-set containing null-values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to sum up a set of values in an XML using XSLT and XPath function fn:sum. This works fine as long as the values are non-null, however this is not the case. To illustrate my problem I've made an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
      <!-- Works fine for non-null values -->
      <sum><xsl:value-of select="fn:sum(values/value)" /></sum>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <values>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <!-- Nullvalue -->
    <value />
  </values>
</root>
```

The example works fine as long as there's no null-values. I've tried various variants of the select, such as `<xsl:value-of select="fn:sum(values[value != '']/value)" />` (as you might notice, not much of an XSLT export ;) ) How can I filter out the null-values?

Comment: Just a note: there is no need to use a prefix like 'fn' to use functions like 'sum' in XSLT 2.0, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#static-context which says: "The default function namespace is the standard function namespace, defined in [Functions and Operators]. This means that it is not necessary to declare this namespace in the stylesheet, nor is it necessary to use the prefix fn (or any other prefix) in calls to the core functions."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Explicitly test that the nodes have content:

```
<sum><xsl:value-of select="fn:sum(values/value[text()])" /></sum>
```

I think that what you mentioned:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:sum(values[value != '']/value)" />
```

does not work, because the node is empty - it does not contain a text node at all, whereas `value != ''` tests for an empty string - that is, a text node having data of length 0.

Answer (score 8):

To sum just the elements that contain numbers:

```
<sum>
    <xsl:value-of select="fn:sum(values/value[number(.)=number(.)])" />
</sum>
```

The result of [`number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions) will be `NaN` for empty elements, or elements whose string value is not a number.

MSDN reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256211.aspx

Answer (score -3):

http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/199909/post60110.html

### **XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <num>1</num>
    <num>7</num>
    <notnum>hello world</notnum>
    <num>4</num>
</doc>
```

### XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/XSL/Transform/1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(/doc/num)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```