# XSLT 1.0 adding values together from multiple nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Say I have the following XML

```
    <A>100</A>
    <B>200</B>
    <C>300</C>
```

and the following XSLT

```
  <TEST>
    <xsl:value-of select="A + B + C"/>
  </TEST>
```

It produces the following output

```
<TEST>600</TEST>
```

however, when one of the nodes is blank

```
    <A></A>
    <B>200</B>
    <C>300</C>
```

I get the following.

```
<TEST>NaN</TEST>
```

I only want to add the nodes that are valid numbers. I could do this if xsl allowed me to dynamically replace a variable value by adding to the already existing variable, but even that would be messy. I assume there is an easy way that I'm missing?

I want XSLT 1.0 answers only please.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using fn:sum in XSLT with node-set containing null-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279314/using-fnsum-in-xslt-with-node-set-containing-null-values)

Comment: Not a duplicate because the other is the sum of one node name, this is summing different nodes together. Plus thats xslt 2.0. I asked for 1.0.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of course but contains a hint on how to test against empty nodes (not specific to xslt 2.0).

Comment: I already knew how to use filters how to test against empty nodes. The issue I was trying to test three different nodes at once that was giving me the problem. Tried A[.!=''] + B[.!=''] + C[.!=''] and had the same issue. got to this before i saw a better answer sum(A[.!=''] | B[.!=''] | C[.!='']). problem is mine doesn't test if its a number, plus I using three filters inside of one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  <TEST>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum((A | B | C)[number(.) = .])"/>
  </TEST>
```

That is, sum the subset of the elements A,B,C consisting of those whose contents can be used as numbers.

Note that `number('')` yields `NaN`, and `(NaN = NaN)` is false, so this will not include elements without text content.

We test for numbers as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3854389/423105

Comment: Note that this test will not work in XPath 2.0, where you "Cannot compare xs:double to xs:string".

Comment: It will work in XPath 2.0 if there is no schema, or if the schema says that A, B, and C are numeric. You *can* compare xs:double to xs:untypedAtomic.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Hmm. The above error was what I received with XPath 2.0 on an XML document that had no schema associated. This was in the XPath 2.0 evaluator in Oxygen XML Editor. I wonder if there was some hidden or default schema that I wasn't aware of?

Comment: @LarsH. Thanks I was looking for something simple like that. I had a solution, but it seemed overkill and messy.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. [number(.)=.] means [number(.)=xs:double(data(.))], and unlike number(), xs:double() doesn't convert '' to NaN, it throws an error.

Comment: @james31rock: glad to help. Also consider Dimitre's answer, which is a little longer but more robust against errors (especially in XPath 2.0).

Comment: Looks like the best answer on SOF for adding two numbers without thinking whitespace or empty nodes.

Answer (score 5):

**A little variation of LarsH's answer**:

```
sum((A|B|C)[number(.) = number(.)])
```

the expression in the predicate doesn't cause any type error in XPath 2.0, because both arguments of `=` are of the same type -- xs:double.

Answer (score 3):

There is also:

For XSLT 1.0:

```
sum((A|B|C)[string(number())!='NaN'])
```

For XSLT 2.0:

```
sum((A,B,C)[string(number())!='NaN'])
```

---

For interest, here is another one. It works for both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0

```
sum((A|B|C)[number()>-99999999])
```

In the above, replace -99999999 with one less than the lower bound of the possible values. This works because NaN > any-thing always returns false. This is probably the most efficient solution yet, but it may be seen as a little ugly.

For example, if you know for a fact that none of A, B or C will be negative values, you could put:

```
sum((A|B|C)[number()>0])
```

...which looks a little cleaner and is still quiet readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/root/*[self::A or self::B or self::C][.!=''])"/>
```

This will add values from A, B, and C under the "Root" element so long as the value isn't blank.

Comment: There are other elements to that I do not want to sum. I specifically want elements A, B and C.

Comment: Updated it to check for element name, try the new one.

Comment: Thanks @Parker. Your answer will work, but LarsH's I went with. Still +1