# Adding Two Values in XSLT

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I Want to Add Childcount Value and Adultscount  Value in XSLT. Can any one please help me to do this in the below example.

My XML Response.

```
  <HotelOccupancy>
              <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
              <Occupancy>
                <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
                <ChildCount>1</ChildCount>
              </Occupancy>
            </HotelOccupancy>
```

---

my XSLT StyleSheet

```
   <td> Sleep Up To:<xsl:for-each select="hm:Occupancy ">


        <xsl:value-of select="hm:AdultCount"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
```

This will Output Sleep Up to 2. instead of that I want display Sleep Up to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the sum function, and exclude blanks or non numerics.

try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum((hm:AdultCount | hm:ChildCount)[number(.) = .])"/>
```

More info: 
[Using fn:sum in XSLT with node-set containing null-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279314/using-fnsum-in-xslt-with-node-set-containing-null-values)